# MongoDB replCallbackWithGlobalLock-0. What does it mean?

Tags: mongodb

I have a production replica set with 3 members (primary, secondary, arbiter). Almost every day, there's a short downtime where the primary is demoted to secondary for no apparent reason.

The replica set log from the primary says this:

```
  "2016-01-18T21:32:07.281-0500 I REPL     [ReplicationExecutor] Member 2.2.2.2 is now in state PRIMARY",
  "2016-01-18T21:32:07.282-0500 I REPL     [replCallbackWithGlobalLock-0] transition to SECONDARY",
  "2016-01-18T21:32:25.264-0500 I REPL     [ReplicationExecutor] Member 3.3.3.3 is now in state ARBITER",
  "2016-01-18T21:32:38.520-0500 I REPL     [ReplicationExecutor] Member 2.2.2.2 is now in state SECONDARY"
  "2016-01-18T21:32:41.688-0500 I REPL     [ReplicationExecutor] transition to PRIMARY",
  "2016-01-18T21:32:42.341-0500 I REPL     [rsSync] transition to primary complete; database writes are now permitted",
```

2.2.2.2 is the secondary. As you can see, the secondary takes over, but I have no idea why. Usually when this happens, the application is unable to connect to the database for a few seconds.

Any explanation will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What version of MongoDB are you using?

Comment: @Stennie version 3.0.4